# How to update all columns in a table with sum of 2 different records in the same table in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table named :- 
**user_calculation** having following columns - **totalLikes, totalComments** And **TotalInteraction** 
[image]

I need to update the column **`TotalInteraction`** with the sum of **`totalLikes`** and **`totalComments`** per user. 
The Result should be like this :-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update user_calculation
set TotalInteracion=totalLikes + totalComments
```